# What is causing this error, No route matches {} missing required keys: [:message_id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following models

Message

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
end
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
    has_many :actions, through: :messages
end
```

Place

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
    has_many :users, through: :messages
end
```

And view:

```
<%= form_for [@message, @place] do |form| %>
    <p>
        User say  
        <%= form.text_field :title %>
        from 
        <%= form.text_field :name%>
        <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

The view rendered from Dashboards Controller show action:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @message = Message.new
        @place = Place.new
        @messages = current_user.messages
    end
end
```

While Title and Name are columns for Message and Place tables:

```
  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "action_id"
  end

  create_table "places", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

I have nested routes because the has_many relationship.

```
  resources :messages, only: [:create, :show] do
    resources :places, only: [:create]
  end
```

Here is how controllers looks like, which I "guess" they casing the problem...

Messages controller

```
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController
        def show
            @message = Message.find(params[:id])
        end

        def create
            message = current_user.messages.build(message_parameters)
            message.save
        end

        private

        def message_parameters
            params.require(:message).permit(:title) 
        end
    end
```

Places controller

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        place = current_user.places.build(place_parameters)
        place.save
    end

    private
    def place
        params.require(:place).permit(:name)    
    end

end
```

When I run app, i got an error:

```
No route matches {:place=>"create", :controller=>"places", 
:message_id=>#<Message id: nil, title: nil, user_id: nil, place_id: nil, 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:message_id]
```

I see routes for `message_places_path` is missing `:message_id`, but I don't if this is true.

Comment: Could you show your entire routes file?  You have musics listed but are using message and place controllers?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. Routs is fixed now. The rest of routes are related to session, user and root